# Launching a service_app from gui_app?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I have created a Tizen 5.5 Wearable native GUI, and native service app.

Both are working fine standalone. GUI app has `appmanager.launch` privilege.

I wish to start the service app from the gui app:

```
if (APP_CONTROL_ERROR_NONE != (error_code = app_control_set_app_id(app_control, SERVICEAPP_ID))) {
    dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "app_control_set_app_id failed (%d)!", error_code);
    return;
}
if (APP_CONTROL_ERROR_NONE != (error_code = app_control_set_operation(app_control, APP_CONTROL_OPERATION_DEFAULT))) {
    dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "app_control_set_operation failed (%d)!", error_code);
    return;
}
if (APP_CONTROL_ERROR_NONE != (error_code = app_control_send_launch_request(app_control, app_control_result, ad))) {
    dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "app_control_send_launch_request failed (%d)!", error_code);
    return;
}
```

Now when this code runs, it logs

```
app_control_send_launch_request failed (-17825757)!
```

I have dig myself into the Tizen code, and this result is `APP_CONTROL_ERROR_LAUNCH_REJECTED`, which has some references here: https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/api/wearable/5.5/group__CAPI__APP__CONTROL__MODULE.html#gaeeb755a791bdbc5a6fc6d41614e80c1b

> **Remarks:** The function returns APP_CONTROL_ERROR_LAUNCH_REJECTED if the
> operation value is APP_CONTROL_OPERATION_LAUNCH_ON_EVENT which is only
> for handling the event from the platform or other application, refer
> to the Event module. **Since Tizen 3.0, the launch request of the
> service application over out of packages is restricted by the
> platform.** Also, implicit launch requests are NOT delivered to service
> applications since 3.0. To launch a service application, an explicit
> launch request with application ID given by the
> app_control_set_app_id() must be sent.

Okay, so let's find out how to create an "in-package" service app:

- https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/packaging-hybrid-application (not matching as it's creating a WEB application for GUI)
- https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/creating-native-service-tizen-wearables-part-2-service-launcher?langredirect=1 (great, this uses a native GUI and native service)

So I wanted to create this so-called *multi package* however Tizen Studio let me down:

[image]

**How can I create multi-packaged native apps with Tizen5.5?**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for updating it here.
In my case of me, I tested it on TizenStduio 5.0 It works fine.
I can make multi-package of wearable 5.5(basicui + service app).
When I see your image, I think that you did not install the fully sdk.
Could you install the sdk again?
Thanks